# surfaceview orientation without main.xml or androidmanifest.xml

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I would like to change the orientation of my SurfaceView from landscape to portrait. I'm doing this without the use of main.xml (rendering it using only java code) and I would like to know how. Most of the questions here deal with camera orientation, but I would like to know if it's possible to play video in portrait instead of landscape through the SurfaceView. Do I use onMeasure() or onLayout()? Any other functions work? Thanks

BTW I have implemented changes in main.xml and androidmanifest.xml, but they have not worked. I also used setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); but does not work as well.

Comment: From my experience this is NOT possible. sorry I don't have any sources to back me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using

`int setOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;`

works.